# A conjecture regarding the sum of a number and its prime factorization

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I am not sure if this a known problem, but I have a conjecture regarding the prime numbers. Since I don't know much analytic number theory, I thought maybe someone here could prove/disprove it.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot \cdot \cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$ be the prime factorization of $n$. Define $\mathcal{S}(n)$ to be the sum of the prime factorization of $n$.

That is
$$\mathcal{S}(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\alpha_{i}p_{i}.$$

---

**Conjecture**: Let $n\in \mathbb{N},$ $n>2$ and  $\tau(n)=\mathcal{S}(n)+n$. Then for any such $n$ there exists a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $\tau^{k}(n)$ is prime.

---

Here, $\tau^k(n)=\tau(\tau(\tau(\cdot \cdot \tau(n))))$ is the composition of $\tau$ taken $k-$times.

To understand the conjecture, let us look at some examples.

For $n=15$, $\tau(15)=15+\mathcal{S}(15)=15+8=23$ thus for $15$, $k=1$.

For $n=30$, $\tau(30)=30+\mathcal{S}(30)=30+10=40$, $\tau(40)=51$ and finally $\tau(51)=71$ is a prime. So $k=3$.

I have verified this to be true up to $10^7$. Moreover, on average, I believe the number of iteration $k$ required to obtain a prime for any $N$ grows at the rate of $\ln(N).$

Any ideas on how to prove it or find a counterexample? Also, if it a known problem or equivalent to a known problem, can someone provide a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Algorithm works quickly on my computer with Mersenne Primes up to $2^{127}-1$. Using $2^{127}-1$ gives a new prime $2437520251998980409772357517906985597413$ quite quickly according to Mathematica PrimeQ test. Trying now with $2^{521}-1$ and algorithm does not appear to be terminating even after a few minutes.

Comment: @JamesArathoon That’s awesome! I think this iterative process is quite good(and probably fast) for selecting candidates for finding new prime numbers.

Comment: I agree very interesting conjecture. Although not a starting prime, starting with $2^{200}-1$ just for the fun of it terminates after a few minutes on my modest PC, with  the prime (according to Mathematica PrimeQ) 6022652426117572672285869714543951974454197303495522196962153

Comment: It seems like a reasonable conjecture just because you're typically increasing $n$ by a relatively small amount at each iteration $n \rightarrow \tau(n)$, and sampling $\Theta(\log n)$ random numbers of size around $n$ is expected to yield a prime.  But barring any additional numerical evidence, I don't see why you think this is better for nominating new prime candidates than just picking random large numbers.